# When trying to display images from an array on a table view, I am receiving an the error "exc_bad_instruction (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0"

Tags: xcode, swift, tableview

To create an "Events" page of an app, I am using table view to list an image, name, and details of the event. You will be able to select an event, as well as add one.

I am currently populating my table with data stored as an array, however when I try to place the images data, I return an error in this line of code:

```
cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]
```

Can anyone help figure out why I am returning this error?

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var names = ["BTown Diner", "Dunnkirk", "Chocolate Mousse", "Lil Wayne", "Annie", "Campus Squad Social"]
    var details = ["Free drink with meal after 12 AM", "LADIES drink free", "10% off all ice cream!", "Lil 500 concert", "an IU Theater Production", "Bring your Squad to the Campus Squad Social"]
    var images = [UIImage(named: "btown_diner"), UIImage(named: "dunnkirk"), UIImage(named: "choco_moose"), UIImage(named: "lilwayne"), UIImage(named: " ")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.detail.text = details[indexPath.row]
        cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


}
```

Additionally, here is my CustomCell.swift file

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var photo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detail: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `names` has a count of 6.

Your table will have 6 rows from `return names.count`. However, your variable `images` has a count of 5.

I think when your function `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called with `indexPath` equal to 5, your images array is out of bounds.